# Replace all the characters of a string except first and last using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I need to replace all the charecters of a given string with "*" except first and last charecters.

if i have a sring like "hello" the output should be "h***o"

How should i do this using javaScript/jquery

Comment: Try first, then come back with your code and we may be able to help.

Comment: Have you tried so far?

Comment: yes i did. but its so lengthy. I am just finding the characters at first and last position then finding the length of a string. then creating a new string of the same length with '*' and adding the first and last characters to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, Check the below one. Try yourself before posting your question.

```js
var strOrg="hello";
var strOrgLen='',strRep='',strDes='',strRepLen='';

document.write("Entered String = "+strOrg + "<br>");

strOrgLen=strOrg.length;

document.write("Entered String Length = "+strOrgLen + "<br>");

strRep=strOrg.substring(1,strOrg.length-1);

document.write("Getting the middle substring except first and last ="+strRep + "<br>");

strRepLen=strRep.length;

for(i=strRepLen;i>0;i--)
  strDes+='*';

document.write("Adding the * according to the substring ="+ strDes + "<br>");

var resStr = strOrg.replace(strRep, strDes);

document.write("Replace the same and final output = "+resStr + "<br>");
```